# XmlPullParser removes "\" in regexp

Tags: java, android, regex, xmlpullparser

I parse following passage:

```
<group start="372" name="Russia" max-len="11" regex="^\d{8}$" curnpay="RUR" capacity="false" inccode="true">

String regExpValue = parser.getAttributeValue(null, GROUP_TAG_ATT_REGEXP);
```

As a result I am getting `regExpValue = "^d{8}$"`, where the "\" is gone. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need double escaping in Java. Because Java does not know something like rawstrings and the string is processed at first and all escape sequences are performed. Since `\d` is not a string escape sequence, only the backslash is removed.

So try:

```
<group start="372" name="Russia" max-len="11" regex="^\\d{8}$" curnpay="RUR" capacity="false" inccode="true">
```